# JQuery with several Elements issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got an anchor in the DOM and the following code replaces it with a fancy button. This works well but if i want more buttons it crashes. Can I do it without a for-loop?

```
$(document).ready(buttonize);   

function buttonize(){
    //alert(buttonAmount);

    //Lookup for the classes
    var button              =   $('a.makeabutton');
    var buttonContent       =   button.text();
    var buttonStyle         =   button.attr('class');
    var link                =   button.attr('href');
    var linkTarget          =   button.attr('target');
    var toSearchFor         =   'makeabutton';
    var toReplaceWith       =   'buttonize';
    var searchButtonStyle   =   buttonStyle.search(toSearchFor);


    if (searchButtonStyle != -1) {      

        //When class 'makeabutton' is found in string, build the new classname
        newButtonStyle      =   buttonStyle.replace(toSearchFor, toReplaceWith);
        button.replaceWith('<span class="'+newButtonStyle
                 +'"><span class="left"></span><span class="body">'
                 +buttonContent+'</span><span class="right"></span></span>');

        $('.buttonize').click(function(e){
          if (linkTarget == '_blank') {
            window.open(link);
          }
          else window.location = link; 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('a.makeabutton')` return a collection of elements, use `button.each(function...)`

Comment: the dom looks like this:

 <div class="buttonView">
  
  <a class="makeabutton button-25px red" href="index.html">Buttonized!</a>
  <br />
  <a class="makeabutton button-30px white" href="index.html">Buttonized!</a>
  <br />
  <a class="makeabutton button-40px red" href="index2.html">Buttonized!</a>

  <br />
  <a class="makeabutton button-25px green" href="index.html">Buttonized!</a>
  <br />
  
 </div>

the classes are for the colors, and the script does only replace it with the values from the 1st element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the each method because you are fetching a collection of elements (even if its just one)

```
var button              =   $('a.makeabutton');
button.each(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var buttonContent       =   btn.text();
    var buttonStyle         =   btn.attr('class');
    var link                =   btn.attr('href');
    var linkTarget          =   btn.attr('target');
    var toSearchFor         =   'makeabutton';
    var toReplaceWith       =   'buttonize';
    var searchButtonStyle   =   buttonStyle.search(toSearchFor);
    ...
};
```

the each method loops through all the elements that were retrieved, and you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current element in the loop

Comment: yay! thanks
demos:
http://preview.miriam-schwarz.com/buttons/
http://preview.miriam-schwarz.com/buttons/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var button              =   $('a.makeabutton');
```

This code returns a jQuery object which contains all the matching anchors. You need to loop through them using `.each`:

```
$(document).ready(buttonize);

function buttonize() {
    //alert(buttonAmount);
    //Lookup for the classes
    var $buttons = $('a.makeabutton');
    $buttons.each(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var buttonContent = button.text();
        var buttonStyle = button.attr('class');
        var link = button.attr('href');
        var linkTarget = button.attr('target');
        var toSearchFor = 'makeabutton';
        var toReplaceWith = 'buttonize';
        var searchButtonStyle = buttonStyle.search(toSearchFor);


        if (searchButtonStyle != -1) {

            newButtonStyle = buttonStyle.replace(toSearchFor, toReplaceWith);
            button.replaceWith('<span class="' 
                               + newButtonStyle 
                               + '"><span class="left"></span><span class="body">' 
                               + buttonContent 
                               + '</span><span class="right"></span></span>');

            $('.buttonize').click(function(e) {
                if (linkTarget == '_blank') {
                    window.open(link);
                } else window.location = link;
            }); // end click
        } // end if

    }); // end each
}
```