# Executing a script on multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have five img-elements, each with the class ".backgroundImage". The script below centers it. How can I tell my script to do it with every individual img without writing the script down 5 times?

```
function resize(){
    var imageWidth = $('.backgroundImage').width();
    var imageHeight = $('.backgroundImage').height();

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if(imageWidth>windowWidth){
        var newWidth = -(imageWidth - windowWidth)/2;
        $('.backgroundImage').css('margin-left', newWidth);
    };

    if(imageHeight>windowHeight){
        var newHeight = -(imageHeight - windowHeight)/2;
        $('.backgroundImage').css('margin-top', newHeight);
    };
};
```

The Script is triggered on document.ready and on window.resize

Comment: [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) Like what was used in the accepted answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907799/jquery-with-several-elements-issue)

Comment: It should apply the CSS to each element as you have already coded it. @cookiemonster - no need for .each() here.

Comment: @j08691: I think the issue is that each element may have a different `width/height`. Right now he's getting the width and height of the first one found.

Comment: @cookiemonster - ah OK, I see your point.

Comment: you are both right, the script does it with every element now but I need it individually because every image has a different width/height

Comment: thanks! I am using .each() again - I always forget about this function as I don't code that often :)

Answer (score 2):

Look into $.each. Something like:

```
$('.backgroundImage').each(function(index, value){
  var width = $(value).width();
  var height = $(value).height();  // Value is each individual img element

  // do your resizing on each value as necessary
})
```

Comment: Or `$('backgroundImage').each(...)`

Answer (score 1):

By passing in a variable

```
function resize(selector){
    var imageWidth = $(selector).width();
    var imageHeight = $(selector).height();

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if(imageWidth>windowWidth){
        var newWidth = -(imageWidth - windowWidth)/2;
        $(selector).css('margin-left', newWidth);
    };

    if(imageHeight>windowHeight){
        var newHeight = -(imageHeight - windowHeight)/2;
        $(selector).css('margin-top', newHeight);
    };
};
```

Now, that said, there is no reason to look up the selector so often:

```
function resize(selector){
    var $image = $(selector);
    var imageWidth = $image.width();
    var imageHeight = $image.height();

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if(imageWidth>windowWidth){
        var newWidth = -(imageWidth - windowWidth)/2;
        $image.css('margin-left', newWidth);
    };

    if(imageHeight>windowHeight){
        var newHeight = -(imageHeight - windowHeight)/2;
        $image.css('margin-top', newHeight);
    };
};

resize('.backgroundImage');
```

Comment: How is this different from the original? You're still only getting the `width` and `height` of the first element the selector finds.

Comment: True, but you are passing in the selector, as oppsed to having one copy of the function for each image that needs it.

Comment: The issue is that each element that needs to be manipulated is being matched by the selector. In other words, `.backgroundImage` is returning `5` elements, and OP thought he would have to somehow write a separate function for each element. Instead he should just use `.each()` on the one selector to work with each individual element.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem exactly but it helps me code better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jQuery plugin as follow,

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.centerImage = function () {
    var operations = {
        resize: function() {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height(),
                imageWidth = this.width(),
                imageHeight = this.height();

            if (imageWidth > windowWidth) {
                var newWidth = -(imageWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
                this.css('margin-left', newWidth);
            }

            if (imageHeight > windowHeight) {
                var newHeight = -(imageHeight - windowHeight) / 2;
                this.css('margin-top', newHeight);
            }
        }
    };

    return this.each(function () {
        var ele = $(this);
        $(window).resize(function () {
            operations.resize.apply(ele, []);
        });
    });
 };
})(jQuery);

Then you can call this as,

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.backgroundImage').centerImage ();
});
```

That's all